# Query to return distinct records ordered by newest association

Tags: activerecord, associations

I have a simple relation

```
Playlist (id, title)

which has_many

Playlistships(playlist_id, post_id)
```

A `Playlistship` is an association between the `Playlist` and `Post` classes. When a user adds a 'post' to a 'playlist', a new 'playlistship' is created.  When a 'post' is removed from a 'playlist', the corresponding 'playlistship' is destroyed.

I would like to create a query which would return 'Playlists' in order of `playlistships.created_at`

Basically, I want to have a view which shows `playlists` which have recently had `posts` added to them via the `Playlistship` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
select * from Playlists P
  join Playlistships S on P.id = S.playlist_id
order by S.created_at
```

To get the most recent Playlistship for each Playlist (that has any posts):

```
select * from Playlists P
  join Playlistships S on P.id = S.playlist_id
where S.created_at = (select max(created_at) from Playlistships where playlist_id = P.id)
order by P.id
```

Comment: I need the distinct results for Playlist. My issue is that I can't seem to get activerecord to order the playlistships by created_at BEFORE I do the join.

Comment: @wuliwong - I edited the answer with a query using a subquery to get the most recent. Did that help you?

Comment: Stupidly, I forgot to mention that I am using Activerecord in Ruby on Rails. I'm going to have to wrangle what you wrote to work in there. I'll let you know how it goes. I'm at my real job right now, so I'll have to try it tonight. Thanks though!

Comment: Sorry it has taken me a while to get back to you. The second query worked! Just one small edit, i needed to change `Playlist` to `Playlists`. Thanks and sorry it took me so long to respond.